# Possible to create two list in Fragment master listview & detail listview in android?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to create two list-view by using fragment in android

1. Crate a master listview,
2. Create a detail listview based on masted listview

By using fragment how to make it?

---

Firstly, thanks for your comment pointing out my mistakes, I will correct my mistake hereafter.

I did the above process by using an individual fragment list on a main fragment. Here's my activity class to handle the fragments:

```
public class MainFragment extends Activity implements Cat_To_Sub_i,Subc_To_Itm_I,Item_To_All_I{

FragmentManager fm;
FragmentTransaction ft;
Fragment fr_sub_cat,fr_Itm_cat;
ItemF iif;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
    setFragment(false,false);

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void cat_to_sub(String cid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SubCatagoryF f_s_cat=(SubCatagoryF) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    if(f_s_cat != null && f_s_cat.isInLayout())
    {
        iif=(ItemF) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);
        iif.cancelItem();
        f_s_cat.callSubCatagory(cid);
        setFragment(true,true);
    }
    else
        setFragment(true,false);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setFragment(boolean subc,boolean Icat)
{
    fm=getFragmentManager();
    ft=fm.beginTransaction();

    fr_sub_cat=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

    fr_Itm_cat=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);

    ft.hide(fr_sub_cat);
    ft.hide(fr_Itm_cat);
    if(subc)
        ft.show(fr_sub_cat);
    if(Icat)
    {
        ft.show(fr_Itm_cat);
    }
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void subc_to_itm(String sid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iif=(ItemF) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);
    if(iif != null && iif.isInLayout())
    {
        iif.callItem(sid);
        setFragment(true,true);
    }
    else
        setFragment(true,true);
}

@Override
public void item_to_all(String Iid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: probably ExpandibleListView should suits your need

Comment: Please edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** what you have already tried and what did not work. After all, the master-detail pattern does not dictate the terms of what the detail looks like, so if you want the detail to be a `ListView`, that's perfectly fine.